# SQL Import/Export defaults to byte stream on export

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, export

So, I've done some research and I can't seem to figure this out.  I'm not sure if it's some setting that I'm missing or what.

For the basic info, running SQL2012, 64 bit, all that good stuff.  I noticed that, for some reason, when I export from a table into a flat file using a query, the data type is defaulting to bytestream.  In the past, it always defaulted to DT_STR and went through without any issues.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT pin from IncrementalDM_Emails
where email in (select email from [7755_forsql])
order by pin
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

[image: Error dialog]

Here's what the export is showing when I select "Edit Mappings..."

[image: Mapping dialog]

Now, this can be easily fixed by simply selecting "DT_STR" under the Mappings dialog but I frequently export using this method so I'd like to find out why it's doing it and fix it so I don't always have to go into the Edit Mappings dialog.

Is it something to do with the query and the use of the `IN` function?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** The data in both tables is stored as varchar(50)

Comment: When you retrieve or load data, SSIS tries to automatically convert it to the correct types. If SSIS can’t implicitly convert the data—and transforming the data within the package doesn't work—you might need to modify the XML mapping files (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\MappingFiles -- folder), stage the data so it’s compatible with both SSIS and the data source, create a custom component that can retrieve or load the data, or implement a solution outside of SSIS to prepare the data.

Comment: That makes sense, but this is happening within SSMS, using the Import/Export tool, not SSIS.  Is this answer agnostic and applicable to SSMS also?

Comment: SSMS on the background creates an SSIS package. At the end it will even allow you to save it as an SSIS package.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Do you want me to post as answer ?

Comment: Yes, please, ill accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you retrieve or load data, SSIS tries to automatically convert it to the correct types. If SSIS can’t implicitly convert the data—and transforming the data within the package doesn't work—you might need to modify the XML mapping files (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\MappingFiles -- folder), stage the data so it’s compatible with both SSIS and the data source, create a custom component that can retrieve or load the data, or implement a solution outside of SSIS to prepare the data.

SSMS on the background creates an SSIS package. At the end it will even allow you to save it as an SSIS package.